# How to make laptop switch to external HDMI monitor when plugged in?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, nvidia, laptop

I have a KVM switch using an HDMI monitor,kb& mouse between a desktop and laptop.  Whenever I switch away from the laptop, it reverts to its internal display, as expected.  The problem is it does not automatically do the reverse -- use the external HDMI monitor when switched back.

The same  behavior is observed from unplugging, replugging the HDMI cable directly to the laptop (no KVM).

Laptop: Ubuntu 16.10 with an nVidia 1060 card.

Comment: I had partial success with the solution described here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1584974#p1584974